# Change the date labels as Day with numbers in full calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am working with  FullCalendar V4 along with Ionic -4 and Angular-8 . In week view it shows me 7 days. I want every day to be displayed as Day with number. For example instead of Monday it should be displaying Day 1. 
Also

> I am planning to display only three weeks so there should be Day
>   label starting with Day 1, Day 2 , Day 3 and all the way to display
>   Day 21

Is there a inbuilt method to do this. Or any other approach to do so. Thanks in advance :)

Current Implementation

```js
columnHeaderText(info){
    if(info){
      return 'Day ' + this.count++
    }
  }
```

```html
<ion-content>
  <full-calendar #calendar 
    [header]="header"
    [defaultView]="defaultView" 
    [plugins]="calendarPlugins" 
    [editable]="editable"
    [events]="events" 
    [eventStartEditable]="eventStartEditable"
    [eventDurationEditable]="eventDurationEditable" 
    [dragRevertDuration]="dragRevertDuration"
    [droppable]="droppable"
    (columnHeaderText)=" columnHeaderText($event)"
    (eventRender)="eventRender($event)"
     
  ></full-calendar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this? and reset 'count' everytime you change to a new 3 week period

```
      var count = 1;
      var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
       //your settings...
        columnHeaderText: (date) => {
          return 'Day ' + count++},
        }
      }
```

**EDIT**

```
 calendarOptions: any;
 dayCount: number = 1;
 ngOnInit() {
   this.calendarOptions = {
        columnHeaderText: () => {
           return 'Day ' + this.dayCount++
        }
  }
```

and change in your html to:

```
 [columnHeaderText]="calendarOptions.columnHeaderText"
```

}

Comment: I have updated my question as I am using Angular. Please look into it

Comment: ColumnHeader text function is not being called on render. Its not modifying any labels :(

Comment: See my update, and dont forget to reset dayCount cause it will just keep adding if you dont

Comment: Hey apologies, I was on Vacation. I appplied this logic and it works Great but a small logic issue is that when I click on previous button (i.e) when the calendar renders previous week the numbers are getting added as well. On first day of the week its 1 , then I click next button and again click previous button, the day 1 is becoming Day 15 because its getting added on both previous and next as well. Any ideas to overcome this situation.

Comment: Yes reset 'dayCount' in viewRender() its called every time you change the view, including using next,prev-buttons

Comment: Sry viewRender() has changed from v3 to v4, you should use datesRender()